# Люди-«чайки»: как назвать этот тип характера иначе?

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика, синонимы

Приведу пример. Людей, которые постоянно берут деньги в долг и не отдают, называют "чайками".
Задача: характер человека, и желательно как таких называют в простонародье, которые  всем помогают, всегда в движении, на которых можно положиться и прислушаться к их мнению.
Заранее всем спасибо за ответы!!!

Comment: Бессеребренник,  насчет «в движении» не знаю,  но человек хороший.

Comment: Лучше "бессребреник".

Comment: Ещё бывает "альтруист".

Comment: Возможно Благодѣтель.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, душа  компании, душа коллектива.

Answer (score 1):

Человеколюб — тот , кто любит людей, помогает им, относится с сочувствием. То же, что и филантроп.

Answer (score 1):

Постараюсь найти штук 10 более-менее близких по значению и интересных слов.

1. **Рубаха-парень** — бескорыстный, открытый в обращении, простой и бесхитростный человек, добряк (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)).
2. **Доброхот** — тот, кто по собственному желанию, охоте участвует в чём-либо, доброжелатель (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82)).
3. **Добродей** — тот, кто совершает добрые поступки, благодетель (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9)).
4. **Честняга** или **честняк** — честный человек (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0)).
5. **Свой в доску** — очень близкий, преданный человек (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83)).
6. **Милостивец** — тот, кто оказывает милости, благодеяния (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86)).
7. **Предстатель** — заступник, покровитель (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)).
8. **Душа нараспашку** — о простом, откровенном, добросердечном человеке (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83)).
9. **Радетель** — тот, кто радеет, заботится о ком-либо, о чём-либо; также **всерадетель** (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)).
10. **Печальник** — тот, кто печётся, заботится о ком-либо, о чём-либо; тот, кто печалится, скорбит о ком-либо, о чём-либо, страдает от их горестей (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)).

Comment: Спасибо за оценку))) По мере сил и времени иногда могу взяться за попытку ответить качественно и полезно:)